# Is it possible to access HttpUtility (System.Web.Services.dll) in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

I am trying to access `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()` normally located in `System.Web`. I've read that Xamarin has added it to the System.Web namespace by referencing `System.Web.Services`. However, I still cannot find ut.

I get the error message

> Error CS0122: `System.Net.HttpUtility' is inaccessible due to its protection level (CS0122)

Is there another way of doing it?

Thanks
Fred

Comment: I ended up using the HttpUtility code from mono and changed HttpEncode/UrlEncode (and the corresponding decode methods) to the ones found in System.Net.WebClient.

Answer (score 1):

1. **add a reference** to the System.Web.dll to your project
2. type:

```cs
var login_data = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
```